# Add to an array that is stored in WordPress _options

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress

I would like to know a way to add to an array in PHP. I am not sure why but when I run my code, instead of adding to the array, it replaces it with the new info.

Users are able to enter 2 values that are going to be stored in the array. I want to be able to look through the array and get all the values that are stored. They are adding them one at a time through a form. This is what I have:

```
$variable_option = esc_html( $_POST['variable_option'] );
$variable_value = esc_html( $_POST['variable_value'] );

$variables[$variable_option] = $variable_value;

update_option( 'bhdesign_variables', $variables );
```

It works to store the value and option in the array, but if I submit the form again, it removes what was there and changes it. Why is it doing that?

Comment: Where does `$variables` come from? If it doesn't include the original values from `wp_options`, it's doing what you've told it to do (overwrite everything).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `update_option` function does 2 things (at most):

1. Check in the database to see if an option named `"bhdesign_variables"` exists. If this option does not exit, it creates a new entry with this name and will store the variable that you passed ( `$variables` ). If the option already exists in the database, then it goes to next step:
2. Updates the value of the option with the new value that you passed. This means that it overwrites anything that you had.

So, if you want to preserve the previous values, you first need to get the existing array from the database, add your new values to it, then update option with the new array.

Something like this:

```
$variable_option = esc_html( $_POST['variable_option'] );
$variable_value = esc_html( $_POST['variable_value'] );

$variables = get_option( 'bhdesign_variables' );   // get the existing array

$variables[$variable_option] = $variable_value;    // add new key to array

update_option( 'bhdesign_variables', $variables );  // write to database
```

Comment: Beautiful!! Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 0):

Hoping not to have misunderstood the question
Why you simply add the value to the array

```
$variable[] = esc_html( $_POST['variable_option'] );
$variable[] = esc_html( $_POST['variable_value'] );
```